# element.style.setProperty(property, value) vs element.style.property = value

Tags: javascript

Are there any implementation or support differences in `element.style.setProperty(property, value)` and `element.style.property = value`?

- Are there any compatibility/browser support issues with one form or the other?
- What are the differences of each syntax?
- Is either form considered a "best practice"?

Comment: It's pretty much based on what works for you.  They both accomplish the same thing in the same way.  No inherent advantages outside of the number of characters typed.

Comment: dont forget:  style['color'] ='black'

Comment: @amon Can you please tell me where I should ask a question like this? (I got referred from Code Review to this forum, normal SO isn't the place to ask either)

Comment: The accepted answer proves that this in **not opinion based**.  As usual, @gnat the answer closing fiend is wrong.

Comment: This is not an opinion based question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There might not seem to be a difference with 'color' but consider:

```
element.style.backgroundColor = 'blue' // works
element.style['backgroundColor'] = 'blue' // works
element.style['background-color'] = 'blue' // does not work

element.style.setProperty('background-color','blue') // works
element.style.setProperty('backgroundColor','blue') // does not work
```

'-' is not illegal in a property name, but the interpreter will think you mean minus. Hence the style object properties can't map directly to css property names.

There seems to be some controversy on the 'best' or 'correct' way to reference css properties on the style object.

The style object has a spec, and that spec lists the *properties* as camelCase, but the setProperty argument has to match the hyphenated value.

Comment: Your comments about camelCase being required for the property names of the `style` object are correct. However, the spec states that using `style.setProperty()` **requires** hyphen-case. Spec: https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-setproperty

Comment: Thats a draft spec and im not sure it supports your assertion.

Comment: Ok, sure it's still in draft, but it's been in draft since at least 2011, and according to MDN, browser coverage is essentially 100%. The spec says it must be "a case-sensitive match for a supported CSS property". 

2011 Spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-cssom-20110712/#the-cssstyledeclaration-interface 

MDN page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty#Browser_compatibility

Comment: which point exactly are you reading? i see "if its a match.." and refernces to long and short hand

Comment: I'm saying that camelCase doesn't work for `.setProperty()`. Here's an example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/REmbom?editors=0010

Comment: The first link I sent you takes you directly to section 6.6.1, then scroll down to the section for `setProperty()`, and then look at no. 2.

Comment: got ya, I cant really remember whether i was saying it would or wouldnt work now. its definely unclear at best. Do you have enough rep to submit an edit?

Comment: Yeah, I fixed one of the results.